# Pepper flash plugin for 32-bit support has ended?

Tags: updates, flash, chromium

Does anyone know if the **32-bit** of pepper flash plugin support has ended?
I use chromium btw.

Comment: That could be the case. Adobe published a separate installation package for PPAPI browsers a few days ago. This is the first time they provided this. I have no confirmation of sources where they made this statement but something is about to change in Chrome and flash.

Answer (score 0):

No, it didn't end in March 2016, and it hasn't ended yet in March 2017

- [Adobe's Flash Player Tech specs / System requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/tech-specs.html) doesn't say anything about only 64-bit Linux (actually only supports 32-bit WinXP & Vista)
- The [Download page (for "another computer" to pick the version)](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) still lists 32-bit Linux (the Win & Mac versions only differentiate between NPAPI & PPAPI, no mention of 32 or 64-bits...)
- The [About Flash Player page](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) seems to have a new version for Firefox on Linux (NPAPI), previously it was frozen around version 10.x and appeared to have had it's support dropped, but now it's back at the same version as every other OS (version 24.x today)